# How do I install odoo v8.0 and development environment on windows 10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to install odoo 8.0 in windows 10 OS so far these are the steps I have been following but when I run odoo.py on command line the odoo server is not initializing.

  Install Odoo for development:

Install Pycharm

Install Python 2.7

Download get-pip.py

python get-pip.py

cd your odoopath

c:\python\scripts\pip.exe install -r requirements.txt

Or C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install --upgrade -r requirements.txt

install simplejson

Install NodeJs

Install VCForPython27.msi

pip install pypiwin32

odoo.py

Create db on pgadmin

Start Odoo with db credentials -- odoo.py -d DHS -r aahi-admin -w DHSNAIROBI

odoo.py -d databasename -r username -w password

First login is admin/admin

Comment: What error are you getting? PLz try to use this as reference https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/how-to-debug-odoo-in-eclipse-under-winows-36105 . I think you are missing some libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in window environment then download and install the 
latest build EXE file from the [odoo nightly server](http://nightly.odoo.com/).

This Package build merged all the odoo related python packages and other dependent files.We have no need to install it separately in our machine.

Every night, a new set of packages is generated for the branches listed below. This set consists of deb and rpm packages for Debian and RedHat distributions, an EXE package for Windows and a source package.

Please pick your favorite odoo version with latest build EXE and use and install it in your system from which same as normal EXE file in the window.

After Installed the odoo.exe file on your machine.
Odoo setup create a new directory in default drive C: which named as Odoo 
and you will also find all add-ons and other server related modules in it.

Also, find the .bat file for starting the odoo instant.
double click on it and run and then odoo servers will start with 8069 port

And see the result in your favourite browser.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks you , but I don't need the exe file I got odoo8 from github and would like to tweek the code inside.

Comment: oh ok Are you using odoo as devaloper perspective or customer perspective ?

Comment: I am using as a developer, I think I have got the solution here: https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/configure-pycharm-odoo-development-windows